# HTML form sending get AND post. Redirecting with 302

Tags: php, html, apache, post, get

When the user clicks submit, it is sending both a post AND get request to the script. The Post returns a 302 Found, and the Get returns a 200, but the print_r shows an empty array after the form is submitted. I can't figure out why this is happening.

This is running on an AWS Linux instance with PHP 5.4 and Apache 2.4.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Login</title>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p>Please login:</p>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];?>" method="post">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            username
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" style="width:400px;"> (case sensitive)
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            password
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" style="width:400px;">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
            <input type="submit" value="submit">
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

When I click submit, this is what I see in the FF dev tools:

[image: dev tols results]

Comment: An HTML form _can not_ submit "using two methods at once." Pretty sure it's POST request send by your form/browser, 302 response send by the server, and then a GET request by the browser. Now why the 302 occurs, is not clear from the code shown so far. For starters, I'd check what the form's action attribute actually contains.

Comment: "it is sending both a post AND get request to the script"  Nope, that's definitely not happening.  Re-check your assumptions.

Comment: You might consider leaving `action` blank.  It will submit to the current URL.

Comment: @CBroe: theoretically you can mix post and get, if you add a querystring to the post action, can't you?

Comment: @Gerfried that would still make it a POST request, which just happens to go to a URL that includes a query string. When you work with the data in PHP, it will populate $_POST and $_GET accordingly - but the method in the first line of the request headers will still be POST nonetheless.

Comment: I just updated the post with a screenshot of what I see in the network panel. As you can see, when I click submit, I get that. The action contains "/path/file.php", where those are the actual path and filenames.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are not sending POST and GET - only POST. 
Your server then responds with a redirect (302) which makes your browser load the given URL via GET. At this point your data is lost (due to the redirect) and the array is empty. The question is why your server instructs to redirect.
The most likely reason is your htaccess file. Could you please send it.

Comment: I did a search and I don't have any .htaccess files. Is it possible it could be in the config file?

Comment: Did you try with different browsers? I read that it might be caused by a missing/wrong data length attribute.